# What determines which tags are listed for a user in the users tab?

Tags: discussion, tagging

When you look at a user in the users tab you can see their reputation, their location (if the user provided one), the number of badges of each class they have earned, and three tags. What determines which tags are listed here?

Comment: I think it is the three tags that the user has earned most reputation in. A lot of homework, algebra-precalculus and calculus experts out there. Linear algebra is also a popular area of expertise. It might be more informative to use other criteria, but this is also telling (and easier to code).

Comment: When I view the tags under my name, they do not match with my three highest reputation earning tags.

Comment: Hmm. I'm no longer sure. It seems to me that the three chosen tags depend (at least) also on the time interval. My tags change, if I switch the reputation league display from "quarter" (=the current default?) to "all". May be other factors are also taken into account?

Comment: As far as I figured it out, these are indeed the tags in which one got the most reputation in the period in question (week/month/quarter/year/all time). So if you have a week in which you get a lot of upvotes in a tag you usually don't participate in, it will be listed on the week view, but (probably) not on the quarter/year/all time views.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Does that work when you look at my profile? When I see my account on the user page with time period 'all' selected, the tags listed are differential-geometry, homework, and reference-request, while my top three tags in terms of reputation for the period are homework, calculus, and linear-algebra.

Comment: Indeed. So much for Occam's razor. It was the simplest hypothesis I could come up with that explained the observed behaviour. Well, until.